# How to check how long the last uptime if it's not shutdown correctly?

Tags: power-management, shutdown, battery

I need to check battery life of some batteries while powering my machine (a BeagleBone). My plan is to plug it in, leave it, and check some time later. If it's dead, then I need to know how long it's uptime. It's connected to internet so the time is updated automatically and always accurate.

Now obviously when the power is depleted it couldn't shutdown, it just powered off, but is there a way to check down to the latest minute of uptime? I'm thinking of a script running in background that starts writing the time each minute and append it to the top of a text file, but probably Linux has a built in functionality for this?

If it doesn't, what do I write for the script and how to autorun it in background? I have zero knowledge of programming.

Please help and thanks.

Comment: `tuptime` record the startup events and the related shutdowns, also it register if they were done correctly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter terminal:

> gedit ba.sh

Copy paste this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash          
while true; do
    date -u >> output.txt
    sleep 1m
done
```

Save, exit, enter terminal:

> chmod +x ba.sh

Then enter:

> ./ba.sh &

This should output date and time to output.txt once per minute. If you like, you can change the interval etc.

Comment: This works! But how do I make it to run automatically after boot?

Comment: sudo gedit /etc/rc.local

Paste the script above the exit 0 and below the comments. Save & exit. It should work in each start. Instead of output.txt you can  give full path to your output.txt so that you dont have to go find it in the etc folder, which probably requires some write permissons etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339555/how-to-run-a-script-at-the-start-up-of-ubuntu

You can find more ways to auto-start scripts on start-up on this link.

Answer (score 1):

With apt-get you can install a system monitoring tool such as *munin*. Don't know if this is right for the BeagleBone, though. [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/Documentation) runs on top of perl and RRDtool, and will collect a whole lot of data, uptime among them. It has a webinterface that can create reports and plots by day, week, month, year. Default measurement interval is by second.

This is what my machine looks like for the year 2015, which I rebooted once per week, or so:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer but it's seems really complicated for my needs, I think it's suited for advanced server monitoring. I installed Munin but I don't know how to get to work, I imagined to install it then open some ip:port but looks like it's not that easy.

Comment: I agree. I also needed to do some fiddling, in particular the logging and the web GUI needed some tinkering to get right. maybe there are other, simpler-to-configure  tools.